# Setting spark.driver.memory on SparkSession

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Trying some mllib JAVA APIs to run some of my regression jobs.

I had a big dataset which caused a stackoverflowerror on spark.
After researching I found that the

```
spark.driver.memory
```

need to be set to get the extra heap space.
I also got I cannot set this as part of

```
SparkSession.builder().config
```

as by that time JVM is created.
So I used spark-shell to create the SparkSession.

Driver memory setting is fine now

```
Spark Properties
Name    Value
spark.app.id    local-1475122816668
spark.app.name  Spark shell
spark.driver.host   10.60.10.234
spark.driver.memory 5g
spark.driver.port   58070
spark.executor.id   driver
spark.executor.memory   5g
spark.home  C:\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\..
```

Now I was expecting

```
SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
```

to return the same session on eclipse as per the documentation

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html

But getting error

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:823)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:823)
```

If I add the master on java code

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
  .builder()      
  .master("local[2]")      
  .getOrCreate();
```

It is creating new session with default memory 1g.

How can I set driver memory in this whole context,
Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If your data set is huge you should run it on some cluster and set the driver memory as part of spark-submit command. You can also  set many memory related settings in spark-submit command easily.

Comment: Yes, that will be the direction. But I am just starting off and my main focus is mllib library part. So just want to run it as quickly as possible. Is my expectation wrong that SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate() should return the already created session @Shankar

Comment: which version of spark is this?

Comment: @user1710158 : you are trying to set the driver memory using spark shell, then you are trying to get the same session using programmatically?